# How can austerity and quantitative easing happen simultaneously?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, keynesian-economics

In 2010 the UK government simultaneously started an austerity program which cut public spending, taking money out of the economy, while enacting a quantitative easing program which injected hundreds of billions of pounds into the economy.

How can these two seemingly conflicting programs co-exist?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is based on the (rather bizarre) misconception that fiscal policy directly affects the money supply.

Answer (score 2):

The division comes from the entities guiding these sets of policies.

The austerity program falls under *fiscal policy*, which is controlled by Parliament. Quantitative easing falls under *monetary policy*, which is controlled by the Bank of England.  The policies enacted by these two entities are not necessarily coordinated, and can sometimes work opposite each other's objective.